# Apostrophe in the editor appears as question mark in the pdf file

Tags: fonts, accents, texshop, french

I am writing my thesis with LaTeX in French (so I use the package `[latin1]{inputenc}`). I use TeXShop to compile and I am a Mac user. I use a template provided by my University.

My code was working very well so far. I could write directly on the editor with special characters, and the compilation resulted as I expected. When I wanted to copy a paragraph from a `.pdf` file, I just had to copy-paste the paragraph and find "'" and replace by "'" and the compilation resulted as I expected.

However, I don't know what I did, now even I write an apostrophe directly in the editor, it appears as question mark in the `.pdf` file. I might have done something wrong when I played with some packages like `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`. But I removed that and it is still the same.

Here is the code I used :

```
%!TEX TS-program = latexmk
%!TEX encoding = IsoLatin

\documentclass[PhD,english,francais]{ulthese}
\ifxetex\else  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}\fi
\usepackage{mathptmx}         % texte et mathématiques en Times
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}  %Pour obtenir des tableaux typographiquement corrects
\usepackage{colortbl} % Pour pouvoir colorier les lignes et les colonnes des tableaux
\definecolor{grisfonce}{rgb}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{grisclair}{rgb}{204,204,204}
\usepackage{soul} % Pour pouvoir mettre en surveillance
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{% 
          colorlinks=true,allcolors=ULlinkcolor,citecolor=blue,pdftitle={Mémoire de thèse}, pdfauthor={Sébastien Meghezi}, pdfsubject={Biomécanique et génie tissulaire}, pdfkeywords={mécanique, génie tissulaire, collagène, cellules, agents de réticulation, remodelage} %
        }
\newcommand{\hlgrisclair}[1]{\sethlcolor{grisclair}\hl{#1}}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\frenchbsetup{%
        CompactItemize=false,         % ne pas compacter les listes
        ThinSpaceInFrenchNumbers=true % espace fine dans les nombres
      }
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\titre{Titre}
\auteur{Auteur}
\programme{Doctorat}
\faculteUL{Faculté}
\annee{Année}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter                    % pages liminaires
\pagetitre                      % production de la page titre
Cet été, dans une forêt française, j’ai ouï un très grand cri.
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents                % production de la TdM
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables                   % production de la liste des tableaux
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures                  % production de la liste des figures
\cleardoublepage
\dedicace{Dédicace} %À ma famille, Qui a forgé ma personnalité et à qui je dois ma persévérance et le goût du travail bien fait.}
\cleardoublepage
\epigraphe{Épigraphe} %L'imagination est plus importante que le savoir.}{Albert Einstein}
\cleardoublepage
\include{remerciements}         % remerciements
\include{avantpropos}           % avant-propos
\mainmatter                     % corps du document
\appendix                       % annexes le cas échéant
\bibliography{library}               % production de la bibliographie
\end{document}
```

I know that my code is messy but I wanted to show all the packages I use. They might interfere...

Thank you very much for your help.

Seb

Comment: Hi and welcome, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Shouldn't affect apostrophes, though. OP: Any reason you are not using UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @cfr Right. OP: Just checked with utf8, works perfectly fine on TL2013.

Comment: just cut-and-pasted the example into an ascii-based emacs window.  the apostrophe in "j'ai" does not show up as an apostrophe, but as the "empty box" meaning it's in another coding system.  and it doesn't appear to be utf-8 either, because it's still the "empty box" when i save it with that coding.

Comment: Can you try deleting the apostrophe and re-typing it?

Comment: @Johannes_B When I use UTF8, the accents over the characters "e" and "i" with accents do not appear in the pdf. By the way, I would like to thank Johannes_B, cfr and barbara beeton for your fast answer.

Comment: @cfr I deleted the apostrophe and re-typed it but the question marks always appear. The other accent are ok.

Comment: @barbara breton I guess that it deals with a coding system issue but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Copy the following to a new test document and try again: J'ai 0 ans.

Comment: @Johannes_B The apostrophe appears with the text you sent me!

Comment: @Johannes_B However, it does not work with the following text I added : "J'ai 0 ans et je m’en vais en vacances". The second apostrophe does not appear.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- that works beautifully, but it's from a web page that is probably based at the lowest common denominator, namely the ascii block of unicode.  it's not from a pdf file, which is where the problem bubbled up from.

Comment: @Mszigmom That is not an apostrophy, that is a u8217 (apostrophe or right single quotation mark) -> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm You can see the visual difference as well ' ’

Comment: If retyping the apostrophe doesn't help, there is something odd in the settings of your editor, even apart from copy-paste issues.

Comment: @Johannes_B Does it mean that previously, when I was typing on the apostrophe button on my keyboard, this character was coded u2019 and now it is coded as u8217? Because, it was working earlier (sorry I don't know that much about unicode).

Comment: @cfr The encoding of my editor is set on Occidental (Iso Latin 1). Do you think it is the right one?

Comment: This is the same number, once in decimal and once in hexadecimal. You can tell your editor to save all files from now on using utf8 (and chanigng the option of `inputenc` to `utf8`) Doing so will make the glyph appear.

Comment: Of course using the ascii apostrophe would be the most easiest solution. But i don't know where to find that on a french keyboard. Sorry.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have already changed the encoding system to utf8 and loaded the package \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. However the other accents do not appear. What is strange, it is that when I close the editor and open the file again, the apostrophes that previously appeared like "'", appear now as question marks, even within the editor.

Comment: Open your old files using your favourite text editor (notepad for example), copy all the text, paste it into your tex-editor (which you just set to utf8) ans save. Inputencoding can be hell.

Comment: You need to save the file in that encoding. Try 'save as'...

Comment: Remember to make a backup first. I don't want you to loose any data :-)

Comment: If I copy-paste my text into notepad, and find and replace the apostrophes, copy-paste the text in the Tex-editor, the compilation is successful. Similarly when I find the 'bad' apostrophes and replace with the 'good' ones, the compilation is successful. However if I type the apostrophe directly in the notepad or in the Tex-editor, the compilation results in question mark. There might be a problem with the configuration of my keyboard. Thank for your help ;)

Comment: @Mszigmo: Most probably, TeXshop uses the Apple Mac encoding by default. You have to change this encoding in TexShop configuration. Most editors nowadays use UTF8, don't know why TeXshop sticks to Apple Mac.

Comment: I went again to the encoding preferences of TeXShop. It was set to "Occidental ISO (Latin 1)", which is coherent with the package I use. I pressed the default button and it changed to "Occidental ISO (Latin 9)". Now the text is compiling perfectly with the good apostrophe and accents. Thanks to everyone for your help!